# Website css and javascript are not accessible within their respective folders

Tags: html, css, apache, .htaccess

My school offers a free website space for each student. I created a website with the following structure

```
 - index.html
 - main-site/
  - css/
     - bootstrap.css
     - style.css
  - img/
  - js/
 - help-docs/
 - template/
```

When I visit the site on my home machine, everything loads fine and the css is applied to the pages.

I then upload the folder to the root of my website for the school. I replace the default `index.html` with mine and place the folders in the same structure as before. But the problem is that when I open the page from the new endpoint, the css is not applied. None of the images are loaded and the website just looks bare.

I've tried changing the permissions of the folders and files to make them accessible but this does not seem to work. I even changed everything to `777` and it does not make a difference.
I got one of my friends to try my website on his page and everything seems to be working well for him. So at this point I'm not sure what the problem is.

I should also add that the webserver is apache

So far, in my .htaccess file, I have the following:

```
DirectoryIndex website.html
```

I have also changed index.html to website.html and now accessing the website by using `website.html` rather than `index.html` still works fine apart from the inability to load css or js files.

Is this something that can be solved using a `.htaccess` file? If so, what could I add to it to make this work? Other solutions are welcome, although it should be noted that I do not have root access

### Index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="author" content="" />
  <!--[if IE]>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<![endif]-->

  <title>Light Wave Template | DesignBootstrap</title>
  <!-- BOOTSTRAP CORE CSS -->
  <link href="main-site/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- CUSTOM CSS -->
  <link href="main-site/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- HTML5 Shiv and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <!-- HEADER SECTION START-->
  <section id="header">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row text-center">

        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-12">
          <h1>Light Wave Template </h1>
          <p>
            <strong>6 Style </strong> Versions
          </p>
          <h4>Click on the image to see demos</h4>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </section>
  <!-- HEADER SECTION END-->
  <!-- PREVIEW SECTION START-->
  <section id="preview">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center">

        <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-12 ">
          <h1>SEE DEMOS</h1>
          <h3> <a href="help-docs/index.html" target="_blank">See Document</a></h3>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="preview-wrapper">
            <a href="template/blue.html" target="_blank">
              <img src="main-site/img/previews/1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
              <hr />
              <p>
                Blue Color Version ( With slider background )
              </p>
            </a>
          </div>


        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="preview-wrapper">
            <a href="template/green.html" target="_blank">
              <img src="main-site/img/previews/2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
              <hr />
              <p>
                Green Color Version ( With slider background )
              </p>
            </a>
          </div>


        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="preview-wrapper">
            <a href="template/red.html" target="_blank">
              <img src="main-site/img/previews/3.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
              <hr />
              <p>
                Red Color Version ( With slider background )
              </p>
            </a>
          </div>


        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="preview-wrapper">
            <a href="template/yellow.html" target="_blank">
              <img src="main-site/img/previews/4.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
              <hr />
              <p>
                Yellow Color Version ( With slider background )
              </p>
            </a>
          </div>


        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="preview-wrapper">
            <a href="template/solid-black.html" target="_blank">
              <img src="main-site/img/previews/5.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
              <hr />
              <p>
                Black Background Version ( With solid background )
              </p>
            </a>
          </div>


        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="preview-wrapper">
            <a href="template/solid-red.html" target="_blank">
              <img src="main-site/img/previews/6.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
              <hr />
              <p>
                Green Background Version ( With solid background )
              </p>
            </a>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- PREVIEW SECTION END-->
  <!-- YES SECTION START-->
  <section id="yes">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            <span class="text-yes">Yes , You heard right !
                            <br />
                            its'free and with documentation</span>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- YES SECTION END-->

  <!-- BOTTOM SECTION START-->
  <section id="bottom">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row text-center">

        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3>Want Some More ?</h3>
          <h4>EXPLORE : DesignBootstrap.com</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row text-center">

        <div class="col-md-12 ">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- BOTTOM SECTION END-->
  <!-- FOOTER SECTION START-->
  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          &copy; 2015 <a href="http://www.designbootstrap.com/" target="_blank">DesignBootstrap.com </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- FOOTER SECTION END-->
  <!-- JAVASCRIPT FILES PLACED AT THE BOTTOM TO REDUCE THE LOADING TIME -->
  <!-- CORE JQUERY SCRIPTS -->
  <script src="main-site/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS -->
  <script src="main-site/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't think this has to do with .htaccess. It sounds like a path problem. Can you post your index.html?

Comment: @BrandonSmith I just posted it. Like I said, my friend was able to do the same thing I did and his worked. So I don't think its a path issue

Comment: Have you tried reaching those files directly? What happens if you go to [path]/main-site/css/style.css in your browser?

Comment: @BSMP I get the error `You don't have permission to access /~aaa111/main-site/css/style.css on this server.` Wierd part is that if I replace my id with my friends', it works. So I think this is a problem with the way my files are configured on the main server

Comment: Are you sure that the permissions are 777? How about the directories? What permissions do they have?

Comment: @BrandonSmith The directories are 700. I have tried changing them to 777 but that did not make a difference so I changed them back to what they were. I'm beginning to think there is no help for me on SO because this problem seems to be specific to my account at school, so I will just wait till monday and go talk tot he IT guys

Comment: It's definitely a strange issue. If you make a new directory outside of main-site and a file inside that, are you able to access it directly?

Comment: @BrandonSmith I wil try that promptly. That's something I haven't tried

Comment: @BrandonSmith, Ok that's was probably the least exepcted option, but it worked! Put that as an answer and we can call this a wrap. Amazing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new directory outside of main-site and moving the files to that directory. This may fix the problem that you are experiencing.

Sounds like there may be a problem with file or directory ownership, but without being able to see it, I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: That was great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Brandon's answer, I found that the actual issue was that the directories I had copied over did not have the right permissions associated with them. After creating a temporary directory, I noticed that the folder had the permission `755`

```
ls -ld tempdir
drwxr-xr-x 2 aaa111 student 4096 Feb 21 18:34 tempdir
```

Whereas the other folders had only permission `700`

To fix, this I ran this command:

```
find main-site template help-docs -type d | xargs chmod 755
```

And now everything works well